# PostgreSQL benchmarking

Tags: postgresql

I am currently trying to benchmark the performance of PostgreSQL when:

1. the tablespace is set to a folder on an ***HDD partition***
2. the tablespace is set to a folder on an ***SSD partition***

I am using the **[pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgbench.html)** tool to perform the benchmarking, and am following the procedure according to ***[this tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/tuning-postgresql-with-pgbench/)***. So basically, I am looking at the tps (avg. transactions per second) at the end of the run as the metric for comparison.

*Note*: The size of my database is close to 10 GB so there is sufficient load for a stress test.

Before each run, I am manually changing the tablespace to **hdd_tbspc** (tablespace on HDD parition) and **ssd_tbspc** (tablespace on SSD parition), using ***pgAdmin***.

#### The question

- However the value that I am getting at the end of each of the runs is more or less the same, i.e., I can't observe any significant performance improvements when I switch to an SSD. Is there any reason for this?
- Also, please let me know if the benchmarking protocol I am following makes sense.

#### Commands used

Here are the commands that I am using:

To initialize and scale the DB:

- `$: pgbench -U postgres -i -s 50 db-name`

The above command is run only once. The two queries shown below are run on the same database with different tablespaces to contrast the performances.

Using the number of transactions as a metric:

- `$: pgbench -U postgres -c 10 -j 2 -t 10000 db-name`

Using time as a metric:

- `$: pgbench -U postgres -c 10 -T 600 db-name`

Comment: @jjanes so I run the `pgbench -i` command once and then for the next commands (-t/-T) will need to be executed on the same database with different tablespaces. So I am instructing the DB/server as to which tablespace is to be used using pgAdmin (right click the DB name > properties > select tablespace from dropdown).

Comment: What are the actual performances?  What do you get from pg_test_fsync from each drive?

Comment: Also, what does `iostat -mNx 1` report for the `%iowait` column? If your workload is I/O bound, you should see values above 10 there.